# Code for filtering bitmap images or QR code

Tags: c#, bitmap, openfiledialog

This is my code, for decoding a bitmap. I want to make it so when the user chooses an image or bitmap that doesn't contain a QR code, it will say something like "Image does not contain code", or when the image is too small.

[This error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skBP1.png) shows up when I try and decrypt a bitmap that doesn't have a QR code.

```
    private void btnDecode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "JPEG|*.jpg", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = false})
        {
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
                MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeDecoder decoder = new MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeDecoder();
                txtDecode.Text = decoder.Decode(new QRCodeBitmapImage(pictureBox1.Image as Bitmap));
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is how my program encrypts text. It makes the text inputted in the textbox a bitmap, then saves it as JPEG.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "JPEG|*.jpg", ValidateNames = true })
        {
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeEncoder encoder = new MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeEncoder();
                encoder.QRCodeScale = 8;
                Bitmap bmp = encoder.Encode(txtEncode.Text);
                pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
                bmp.Save(sfd.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
        }
    }
```

> Please do note that I'm new to c#

Comment: Why not just simply wrap your `decoder.Decode(...)` in a try-catch statement. Then, if it succeeds just continue, but if an exception is caught you can `MessageBox.Show` your error message and abort

Comment: Note that encoding != encryption. The former only transforms the data into some other representation, i.e. a qr code in this case. The later uses some kind of secret to transform the data. You could *encrypt* the text before *encoding* it, but that is not what you are doing.